# JS regex - how to add the spaces to the symbols that i have found using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

i am looking for the symbols using this regular expression

```
/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/g
```

I'd like to add the spaces between these symbols with both sides.
For example: `"Hello,my name is Max"`

I'd like this string to look like `"Hello , my name is Max"`.

How can i do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/([-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/])/g
```

and replace by

```
 space\1space
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/9Qa071/3)

Comment: It is exactly what i need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The code you need is:

```
result = subject.replace(/[\-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/g, " $& ");
```